# Month's in the right order Python

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I need some help. I want to make a histogram where you have different dates(Year and Month). I sorted the Months and Year but it is not in the right order. Can someone help me?

This is my code:

```
df["Report Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Report Date'])
df_gesorteerd = df.groupby(df['Report Date'].dt.strftime('%B %Y'))['Agency Id'].sum()
```

The spider console gives me the following information:

```
Report Date
April 2016        70926
April 2017        69953
April 2018        67335
August 2016       71694
August 2017       74894
August 2018       69463
December 2016     67162
December 2017     68038
February 2017     63745
February 2018     62229
January 2017      66202
January 2018      69533
July 2016         66205
July 2017         71750
July 2018         65111
June 2016         69645
June 2017         68122
June 2018         61306
March 2016           88
March 2017        74489
March 2018        67672
May 2016          71183
May 2017          74714
May 2018          70341
November 2016     67342
November 2017     66511
October 2016      74240
October 2017      71187
September 2016    72979
September 2017    72342
September 2018    67844
Name: Agency Id, dtype: int64
```

You can see that the Months as well as the Years are not in the right order, I did like to see the following code appear on my screen:

```
Report Date
March 2016 88
April 2016 70926
June 2016 69645
...
```

When I have this information I did like to make a histogram with on the X-axis the Report Date and on the Y-axis the number of calls?

Can anayone help me?

Comment: How working `df_gesorteerd = df.groupby(df['Report Date'].dt.strftime('%B %Y'), sort=False)['Agency Id'].sum()` ?

Comment: `import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
df["Report Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Report Date'])
#sorting datetimes if necessary
df = df.sort_values('Report Date')
#parameter sort=False for avoid default sorting in groupby
dates = df['Report Date'].dt.strftime('%B %Y')
df_gesorteerd = df.groupby(dates, sort=False)['Agency Id'].sum()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181708/discussion-on-answer-by-jezrael-months-in-the-right-order-python).